# How to change partitioned frame title number from Roman to Arabic?

Tags: beamer

### Problem

When `allowframebreaks` is turned on, long data will be divided into several slides.
Each slide in this partition has the same title ending with a unique number in Roman.

How to change this number from Roman to Arabic?

---

### Screenshot

[image]

---

### Code Snippet

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{A}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit 1

On page 60 of [beamer's manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) there is an info about this but I have no idea how to do this because the convention and terminology used there is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beamer manual (section 8.1) describes how to do this, you need to change the beamer template `frametitle continuation`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{A}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```