# unwanted vertical line appears in the contents for beamer

Tags: beamer

I don't really understand why this vertical line appears in the contents. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{
XXXXXXXXXXXX}
\date{January  $25^{th}$, 2222}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Contents: }
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5cm]{\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the counter for `allowframebreaks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical bar is really an uppercase `I`, and is there because you've allowed frame breaks in this slide. If your table of contents extends over multiple frames, the first one will have the title "Contents: I," the second will be titled "Contents: II," and so forth.

To fix this, place `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}` somewhere in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Contents:}
    Chocolate tea!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [this TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8376/55879) for a little more information on the frametitle continuation.